# Riemann integration of a power function

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to prove
$$
\int_1^\infty x^{-a}dx =\frac{1}{a-1}
$$
for $a > 1$ using the definition of the Riemann integral (i.e. without appealing to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).
To do so, I first construct the definite integral
$$
\int_1^bx^{-a}dx
$$
for $b > 1$.
Let $1 = x_0 \leq x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n = b$ denote a partition $P$ of $[1,b]$.
Define
\begin{align}
U(P) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i-1}^{-a} \Delta x_i \\
L(P) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{-a} \Delta x_i 
\end{align}
where $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$.
Then the upper Riemann integral is equal to $\inf_P U(P)$ and the lower Riemann integral is equal to $\sup_P L(P)$.
Since the partial sums don't seem to have a convienent closed form, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I have not written out the details, and maybe they would be very unpleasant. However, **maybe** the following would work. Roughly speaking use intervals that grow like $\theta^n$ where $\theta$ is close to $1$, and then let $\theta$ approach $1$. Detaills should be all over the Web, I looked for **Fermat Method of Integration** and got lots of hits.

Comment: The idea works very smoothly for finding areas under power curves, I have gone rhrough it for students a number of times. The technical issue is relating to general Riemann sums. If we can assume rhar the integral from $1$ to $b$ **exists**, much of the pain goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}x^{-a}\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^a} \tag{1}$$
since the RHS is converging by the $p$-test. On the other hand,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^a} = \lim_{n\to +\infty} n^{a-1}\sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{k^a}\tag{2}$$
is almost a telescopic series. In particular, since:
$$ \frac{1}{k^{a-1}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{a-1}}=\frac{a-1}{k^a}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{a+1}}\right)\tag{3}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{k^a} = \frac{1}{(a-1)n^{a-1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^a}\right) \tag{4}$$
and the claim follows.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having a little trouble following the logic from (3) to (4). In particular, it is unclear to me how we know $\sum_{k>n}^\infty O\left(\frac{1}{k^{a+1}}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{n^a}\right)$.

Comment: @David: make a comparison between the series and an integral.